# Making subclass class from base class struct

Tags: c++

I have a library given to me where I am supposed to subclass one of its `struct` for use in my own app. When I do this, it works fine. However, when I change my subclass definition to `class` instead of struct (and I make sure to `public:` before everything inside), the compiler (Visual Studio compiler 10) gives me this odd error:

`typecast: conversion exists but is inaccessible`

The line on which this error occurs looks like this:

`LibraryNameSpace::Client c(config_options, &mySublassObject);`

I don't understand why a simple change from `struct` to `class` creates this error; any compiler-added default constructors would apply to either `struct` or `class`, including conversion constructors (if that's the issue here).

Is it perhaps because creating a `class` subclass from a `struct` base class is not a good idea?

Comment: changing from struct to subclass shouldn't cause the error. Maybe Client constructor is defined as explicit ?

Comment: @JohnPoison nothing marked explicit, but there is an answer that is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Members of a 'struct' are public by default, whereas members of a 'class' are private by default. If you do not specify public/private, all members in the 'struct' become private when you change it to 'class'.

Also did you inherit by private or public?

```
class Subclass : public SuperClass {
public:
    // ...
};
```

Comment: You nailed it, thanks. I did not have either `public` or `private` listed; so I guess the default must not be public? When I added `public` it worked. The question is: why?

Comment: @OpenLearner If you didn't specified inheritance method then will be used default inheritance which is private. It makes all inherited properties and methods private